# problemas al hacer una peticion get

Tags: android, android-studio

Explico la situación:

Doy permisos para  el uso de internet en el **manifest** y luego quiero hacer una petición sin respuesta por **get** a una web

Si escribo (para probar) en la URL funciona bien
http://iva.whatsline.com/Carga.aspx?key=1|542233223322|0

Pero si lo escribo dentro de un boton en el **android studio** no llama

Lo hago de la siguiente manera:

```
 try {
            url = new URL("http://iva.whatsline.com/Carga.aspx?key=1|542233223322|0");
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
               Log.e("respuestaA", String.valueOf(urlConnection));
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
               Log.e("respuestaB", "BBB");
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
               Log.e("respuestaC", "CCC");
            }
```

si me pueden ayudar

Mi logcat dice:

> 04-16 15:56:16.693 30759-30759/com.example.notebook.respuestas
>   D/ViewRootImpl@db21b33[MainActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1
>
> 04-16 15:56:16.695 30759-30759/com.example.notebook.respuestas
>   D/ViewRootImpl@db21b33[MainActivity]:
>   mHardwareRenderer.initializeIfNeeded()#2
>   mSurface={isValid=true482020271616}
>
> 04-16 15:56:16.699 30759-30759/com.example.notebook.respuestas
>   V/InputMethodManager: Starting input:
>   tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@48d8852 nm :
>   com.example.notebook.respuestas ic=null
>
> 04-16 15:56:16.699 30759-30759/com.example.notebook.respuestas
>   I/InputMethodManager: [IMM] startInputInner -
>   mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
>
> 04-16 15:56:16.707 30759-30776/com.example.notebook.respuestas
>   D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=83
>
> 04-16 15:56:16.707 30759-30759/com.example.notebook.respuestas
>   V/InputMethodManager: Starting input:
>   tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@1383723 nm :
>   com.example.notebook.respuestas ic=null
>
> 04-16 15:56:18.116 30759-30759/com.example.notebook.respuestas
>   D/ViewRootImpl@db21b33[MainActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage
>   processPointer 0
>
> 04-16 15:56:18.119 30759-30759/com.example.notebook.respuestas
>   W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown
>   path:/system/framework/QPerformance.jar
>
> 04-16 15:56:18.12030759-30759/com.example.notebook.respuestas
>   E/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : Exception_1 =
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:Didn't find class
>   "com.qualcomm.qti.Performance" on
>   path:DexPathList[[],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/lib64,/vendor/lib64]]
>
> 04-16 15:56:18.120 30759-30759/com.example.notebook.respuestas
>   V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = null
>
> 04-16 15:56:18.26530759-30759/com.example.notebook.respuestas
>   D/ViewRootImpl@db21b33[MainActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage
>   processPointer 1
>
> 04-16 15:56:18.278 30759-30759/com.example.notebook.respuestas
>   D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using
>   platform default
>
> 04-16 15:56:18.279 30759-30759/com.example.notebook.respuestas
>   E/respuestaA:
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl:http://iva.whatsline.com/Carga.aspx?key=1|542233223322|0

Comment: Es importante revises en el LogCat cual es el problema que muestra.

Comment: Por cierto Mariana, realizando un GET con la url marca un error 500 : http://iva.whatsline.com/Carga.aspx?key=1|542233223322|0

Comment: Perdón mi ignorancia, es que son mis primeras pasos esta es la linea completa yo trate de recortala

"http://iva.whatsline.com/Carga.aspx?key=1|542233223322|0|mensaje|4|1523047094000|0|1|0|444"

Comment: No tienes porque disculparte, aquí todos aprendemos de todos, @Mariana  para obtener el resultado de la petición no se realiza solo al obtener el valor de urlConnection, revisa la respuesa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La respuesta no se obtiene únicamente convirtiendo el valor de la conexión a String:

```
   Log.e("respuestaA", String.valueOf(urlConnection));
```

A partir del `InputStream` obtenido puedes obtener cada linea de información y almacenarla en un `StringBuilder`:

```
              try {
                        url = new URL("http://iva.whatsline.com/Carga.aspx?key=1|542233223322|0|mensaje|4|1523047094000|0|1|0|444%22");
                        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                        try {
                            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());

                            BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                            StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
                            String line;

                            //Obtiene contenido de la respuesta.
                            while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
                                total.append(line).append('\n');
                            }
                            //Imprime respuesta.
                            Log.e("respuestaA", "valor respuesta: " + total.toString());
                        } finally {
                            urlConnection.disconnect();
                        }


                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

Algo importante es evitar `NetworkOnMainThreadException` que se genera al realizar tareas en el hilo principal, por lo tanto puedes usar un `AsyncTask`  de esta forma:

```
    AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            /**************************************/
            try {
                url = new URL("http://iva.whatsline.com/Carga.aspx?key=1|542233223322|0|mensaje|4|1523047094000|0|1|0|444%22");
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                try {
                    InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());

                    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                    StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
                    String line;

                    //Obtiene contenido de la respuesta
                    while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
                        total.append(line).append('\n');
                    }
                    //Imprime respueta
                    Log.e("respuestaA", "valor respuesta: " + total.toString());
                } finally {
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }


            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            /**************************************/
       }
    });
```

Comment: Esta persona realmente es un genio, mis aplausos y lo mejor para vos, Aunque no creo que lo necesites porque sos super capaz

Comment: @Mariana muchas gracias Mariana , todos somos capaces yo también inicie desde cero, muchos saludos!