# 0 dispositivos compatibles al tratar de subir a grplay store

Tags: java, android

Al tratar de subir siempre me marca que es compatible con 0 dispositivos, por mas que trato de agregar campos al graddle o demas sigue apareciendo que es compatible con 0 dispositivos.

Esto es lo que tengo en el graddle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    lintOptions{
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mx.name.example"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 6
        versionName "3.0.111"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9.13'
    implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:6.0.0'
    implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'


}
```

Esto es lo que tengo en el manifest, he utilizado algunas herramientas y por lo que he visto parece ser que es con lo de apache, busque informacion pero solo salen versiones antiguas de "compil"

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>


    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera2"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.autofocus" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">

        <uses-library
            android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
            android:required="false" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"/>
    </application>
```

La verdad ya he investigado, pero no hallo manera, vuelvo a subir nuevas versiones al play store y sigue apareciendo lo mismo.

Ojala alguien pueda ayudarme, ya que no me habia pasado anteriormente.

Comment: Hay mas actividades, pero no podia publicar asi que solo borre algunas actividades del manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Existen dos causas que determinan en que dispositivos puede ser usada tu aplicación:

**La primera es el uso de libraries Apache**

```
<uses-library
    android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
    android:required="false" />
```

**las [libraries Apache están marcadas como obsoletas](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html?hl=es-419#behavior-apache-http-client), esto para Android 6.0 (API 23) o posterior**

la solución correcta es usa la clase **[HttpURLConnection](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html)**, en el sitio puedes encontrar varios ejemplos:

[App Android crashea al obtener un HttpResponse<JsonNode>](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/277789/app-android-crashea-al-obtener-un-httpresponsejsonnode/277941#277941)

[problemas con makeHttpRequest](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/145050/problemas-con-makehttprequest/145537#145537)

[problemas al hacer una peticion get](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/156317/problemas-al-hacer-una-peticion-get)

**La segunda causa es que estas definiendo el uso de la camara y la propiedad "autofocus" como requisito para el uso de tu aplicación**, únicamente los dispositivos que tengan estas propiedades de hardware podrán usar tu aplicación.

Si no es esencial el uso de la camara  y del autofocus para tu aplicación puedes definir como no requerido forzosamente mediante `android:required="false"`:

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera2"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.autofocus"
    android:required="false" />
```